Rechart XAxis labels backgournd color
Having this recharts ResponsiveContainer
    <ResponsiveContainer width="90%" height={400}>
      <BarChart data={data} barSize={100}>
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" vertical={false} />
        <XAxis dataKey="week" axisLine={false} tickLine={false} />
        <YAxis
          domain={[0, paddedMaxValue]}
          ticks={ticks}
          axisLine={false}
          tickLine={false}
        >
          <Label
            value={stackId === 'deck' ? 'm2' : 'm3'}
            angle={-90}
            position="insideLeft"
            fill="black"
          />
        </YAxis>
        <Tooltip />
        {renderBars(data, stackId, handleBarClick)}
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>

I want to give XAxis labels a background covering the entire area highlighted by Tooltip

I want something like this

